# Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest file must be "instantiatable" by the system

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

It works in debug mode but fails for release build but what's wrong exactly?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyService: LifecycleService() {
```

> app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:48: Error: MyService
> must extend android.app.Service [Instantiatable]
> android:name=".features.record.service.MyService"
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Explanation for issues of type "Instantiatable":    Activities,
> services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest    file
> (or for custom views, in a layout file) must be "instantiatable" by
> the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have an
> empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a
> static    inner class.
>
> 1 errors, 0 warnings

[image]